# Member function pointer to function object

Tags: c++, functor, pointer-to-member

I have a class with a function pointer as a member. In a certain case I would like that pointer to point to a function object, is that not possible?

```
class C {
public:
    C();
private:
    void (*p)();
    struct Functor {
        void operator()() {
        }
    };
};

C::C() : p(Functor()) {
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    C c;
}
```

I get:

```
t.cpp: In constructor 'C::C()':
Line 12: error: cannot convert 'C::Functor' to 'void (*)()' in initialization
```

Comment: By definition, no. Why you would expect to be able to do that?

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not possible. The type of `Functor` is not even close to the type `void(*)()`. You can either change the member `p` to be of type `Functor`, or what you may be looking for is [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function):

> `std::function` is a general-purpose polymorphic function wrapper. Instances of std::function can store, copy, and invoke any callable target -- functions, lambda expressions, bind expressions, or other function objects.

Answer (score 1):

No, a Functor object is not a function pointer. If you would like to initialize p as a Functor, you should declare it as such:

```
class C {
public:
    C();
private:
    struct Functor {
        void operator()() {
        }
    } p;
};
```